# How can I simply remove the fish-eye effect of my DJI Phantom vision 2 lens?

Tags: distortion, fisheye

I'm searching a simple and cost-less way to remove the fisheye effect by:

1. adding a material (additional corrective lens)
   or
2. find the right software (free if possible) to remove the fisheye effect on my pictures

Comment: This question is not a duplicated one, I'm not only searching for a software solution. I'm also searching for an hardware solution that will avoid me to batch-process all of my images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt there's a hardware solution to this, and if there were one, it's likely to cause a decrease in image quality.  Software is your solution, here.

From [the DJI website for the Phantom 2 Vision minidrone](http://www.dji.com/product/phantom-2-vision/feature):

> A lens profile released by Adobe for DJI Phantom 2 Vision's camera
>   can be used to remove lens distortion

DJI keeps it here:
http://download.dji-innovations.com/downloads/phantom-2-vision/en/PHANTOM_VISION_FC200_Files_and_Instruction_en.zip

This would require that you use post-processing software that understands adobe lens profiles (e.g., Lightroom), but that would probably be the fastest, easiest way to batch-process a number of photos to remove the distortion of the lens, particularly if you're shooting in DNG.